# Reflection and Dapper

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, dapper

I'm trying to map my classes with specific Attribute then QueryAsync< T > of Dapper
but, since I don't know the < T > generic parameter I'm trying call QueryAsync return IEnumerable< T > based on runtime Type variable. Is it possible?

I'm try with method overload of QueryAsync

```cs
Task<IEnumerable<object>> QueryAsync(this IDbConnection cnn, Type type, string sql)
```

It returns IEnumerable< object>, but I need return "IEnumerable of < reportType >" reportType is a **Type** object, I know that's not possible to use generic with variable, It's just example

```cs
private static IEnumerable<Type> GetMyReports(Assembly assembly)
{
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MapReportAttribute), true).Length > 0)
        {
            yield return type;
        }
    }
}

var myReports = GetMyReports(myAssembly).ToList();

foreach(Type reportType in myReports)
{
  using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("..."));

  var rows = await con.QueryAsync(reportType , ".. query ..");

  //rows is IEnumerable<object>. Is it possible with some method of Dapper, return """IEnumerable<reportType>""" ???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution could be to make your own generic wrap method to switch to a context where you know T.

```
var myReports = GetMyReports(myAssembly).ToList();
var method = typeof("your class").GetMethod("QueryWrapperAsync", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

foreach(Type reportType in myReports)
{
    var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(reportType);
    genericMethod.Invoke(null, null);
}
    
private static async Task QueryWrapperAsync<T>()
{
    using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("..."));
    var rows = await con.QueryAsync<T>(".. query ..");
    //do stuff
}
```